# CakePHP 2.0.5 form input datetime language

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

How I change language of input datetime in Cakephp 2.0.5?

In CakePHP 1.3, I use default.po, and works great.

```
 // app/Config/core.php
 Configure::write('Config.language', 'pt-br');

 // app/Locale/pt_br/LC_MESSAGES/default.po    
 msgid "January"
 msgstr "Janeiro"
 ....
```

In Cakephp 2.0.5, **default.po** doesn't work.

My input is that:

```
 <?php echo $this->Form->input('melhor_horario', array('dateFormat' => 'DMYHS',
 'separator' => ' de ', 'minYear' => date('Y'), 'maxYear' => date('Y') + 1, 
 'timeFormat' => 24, 'interval' => 15, 'class' => 'span2', 
 'default' => date('Y-m-d 15:00', strtotime('sunday')))) ?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put the translations in a correct domain. Cake 2 uses "cake" domain internally, so the correct path is **Locale/[lang]/LC_MESSAGES/cake.po**

Comment: Yes/No. Because default.po works for everything. But I'll test with cake.po, wait a moment.

Comment: unfortunately does not work for me. anyway, thanks my friend.